# Why pandas Dataframe allow to compare a string column to a timestamp column? and what is the logic

Tags: python, pandas

I am in Python 2.7.

I want to understand how is the decision being made in the first example in below? is it always return True?

I would think this should throw an error since string and Timestamp is not directly comparable. In my second example, I take the individual value from the two dataframe and compare, it indeed causes an error.

```
str_df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b'], columns=['str'])
time_df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('2018-12-12'), pd.Timestamp('2018-12-14')],columns=['date'])
str_df['str'] > time_df['date']

Out[30]: 
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool

Out[31]: str_df.at[0, 'str'] <time_df.at[0,'date']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pithon.shared - Copy\prod\400.123\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-32-d6617ccabf86>", line 1, in <module>
    str_df.at[0, 'str'] <time_df.at[0,'date']
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 941, in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__richcmp__ (pandas\tslib.c:18619)
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'
```

Comment: If it's python3, then this won't even work: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: Same here dose not work

Comment: does works in python 2.7, does not work in python 3.6 ; don't know why